# jQuery split and each

Tags: jquery, split

I'm trying to create breadcrumbs from a string, something like:

```
var str = 'home/files/';
var crumbs = [];
crumbs = str.split('/');
var nav;
$.each(breadcrumbsUrls, function(u, i) {
   if (i.length !== -1) {
      nav += '<a href="'+u+'"></a> ' + i + ' <span class="arrow">→</span> ';
    }
});
```

but I keep ending up with:

```
undefinedhome → files → →
```

the result should be:

```
home → files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = 'home/files/';
var crumbs = [];
crumbs = str.split('/');
crumbs = jQuery.grep(crumbs, function(n, i){ // remove all empty values from array using this
  return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
var nav = '';
$.each(crumbs, function(u, i) {
    if((crumbs.length-1) != u) { // if not last record - add arrow
        nav += '<a href="'+u+'"></a> ' + i + ' <span class="arrow">→</span> '; 
    } else {
        nav += '<a href="'+u+'"></a> ' + i;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'home/files/';
var crumbs = [];
crumbs = str.split('/');
var nav = ''; // changed
$.each(breadcrumbsUrls, function(u, i) {
  if (i.length >0 ) { // changed
   nav += '<a href="'+u+'"></a> ' + i + ' <span class="arrow">→</span> ';
  }
});
```